# Definition in some old paper about formal power series (automata theory)

Tags: automata-theory, definitions

I have a question about a term in a paper about formal power series. It was never defined but the author used $K \langle A \rangle$, what set is $K \langle A \rangle$? Here $K$ is a field (commutative or not) and $A$ is an alphabet. I know that K$\langle \langle A \rangle \rangle$ is the set of all formal power series from $A^*$ to $K$.

Here the paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0020019097001622

Comment: $K\langle A \rangle$ is (probably) the noncommutative polynomial ring whose set of variables is A. I believe this is the same notation as used in Berstel & Reutenauer's book "Noncommutative Rational Series with Applications"

Comment: In all texts on formal power series I have seen, $K\langle A \rangle$ is the subset of $K\langle\langle A \rangle\rangle$ with "finite support", meaning only a finite number of coefficients are non-zero. As @JoshuaGrochow says, they are usually called polynomials.

Comment: The book "Automata-Theoretic Aspects of Formal Power Series" by Arto Salomaa and Matti Soittola might be a good resource: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-6264-0